# Word for an adjective of a group

Tags: single-word-requests

We have a word for an adjective of a country: demonym, but do we also have a word for the adjective of a group? For example, people who belong to reddit are redditers, and this is an adjective for the group of reddit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually two words that come to mind here. Both of these primarily refer to people in a culture, or geographical area, but can also refer to a non-geographical group as well.

The first is ***exonymn***

1. a name used by foreigners for a place, as Florence for Firenze.
2. a name used by foreigners to refer to a people or social group that the group itself does not use, as Germans for Deutsche.

The second term is ***endonymn***

1. a name used by natives for a place, as Bharat for India.
2. a name used by a group of people to refer to themselves, their region, or their language, as opposed to a name given to them by other groups.

However, there isn't a term that encompasses both of these meanings, nor a word that negates the geographical implication. Also, being modern linguistic constructions, these words aren't found in any major dictionary.

Comment: You've written endonym twice! But yeah, sounds like the word I'm looking for, if you take it out of geographical context

Comment: Oh yeah, let me change that